# Redirect from one website to another and keep directory

Tags: html, .htaccess, server, hosting

The blog section of a website moved from a subdomain to a directory of the main domain. I need to redirect all users visiting `blog.site.com` to `site.com/blog/` and the directory someone enters should be kept when forwarding, e.g. `blog.site.com/post/welcome` should point to `site.com/blog/post/welcome`

I treid adding this to my `.htaccess` file which I placed in the subdomain's directory via FTP:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.herderzeitung.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.blog.herderzeitung.de$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://herderzeitung.de/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working. I was also wondering, what the most SEO friendly way is to achieve this (the site permanently moved to another domain).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "this doesn't seem to be working" - What do you mean by this exactly? Are you getting an undesirable redirect? An error? No redirect at all? Where does the subdomain point to in relation to the main domain?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}       ^blog\.herderzeitung\.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.blog\.herderzeitung\.de$
RewriteRule  ^/?(.*)$ https://herderzeitung.de/blog/$1 [R=302,L]
```

I've escaped the dots, and anchored&normalized the pattern. Also switched it to temporary redirects (302); once you know it works, then change it to 301 again for SEO reasons.

And yes, as far as i know `301`s are the best method for retaining your search rankings and the like.

Comment: "I've escaped the dots, and anchored&normalized the pattern." - Although these minor changes won't make any real difference to how the directives actually work. If the directives in the question did "not work" then neither will these. (?)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://herderzeitung.de/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: This is really no different than the rule you posted in the question (the preceding _conditions_ would have been superfluous, assuming you are making a request for the subdomain as stated). More likely is that you had a _caching_ issue. (The `RewriteCond` directive you've posted above is also entirely superfluous and should be removed.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).